# Chain of promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a chain of `Promise` like below code. I want the third `Promise` to wait for finishing the second one, but it dosn't! Can anyone explain the problem?

```js
var condition = true;

// Promise
var willIGetNewPhone = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        if (condition) {
            var phone = {
                brand: 'Samsung',
                color: 'black'
            };
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log("First Prommis!");                        
                resolve(phone); 
            }, 2000)
        } else {
            var reason = new Error('Has not condition!');
            reject(reason); 
        }

    }
);

var showOff = function (phone) {
    var message = 'Need New Phone ' +
                phone.color + ' ' + phone.brand + ' phone';
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Second promis!");
        return Promise.resolve(message);
    }, 1000)
};

willIGetNewPhone
.then(showOff) 
.then(function (fulfilled) { 
    console.log("Third Pramis!");     
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't return a Promise from the `showOff` function. Actually your returning nothing.

The code `return Promise.resolve(message);` returns the anonymous function you created for `setTimeout`, *not* the `showOff`-function.

So you have to return a promise like this:

```
var showOff = function (phone) {
    var message = 'Need New Phone ' +
                phone.color + ' ' + phone.brand + ' phone';
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(message);
        }, 1000);
    });
};
```

So you see, basically your debugging-timeout is your problem.